# Presence heartbeat unable to reach Pubnub servers.{"message":"timeout"}

Tags: node.js, pubnub

In my nodejs application I am getting this error:

```
Presence Heartbeat unable to reach Pubnub servers.{"message":"timeout"}
```

Comment: can you share your pub nub initialization code ?

Comment: It would be best if you could share your node script with us at support@pubnub.com and we can answer back here. Please include sub/pub keys in the script.